# How to represent a condition that links 2 consecutive entities in a relational database?

Tags: database, orm, relational-database, entity, entity-relationship

I'm having a general object `ObjectBlock` which I want to use in a relational database. Each block has a list of entities named `Object`. The difference between this and a normal one-to-many relationship is that I would like to store an operation between 2 sequent objects from the block (ex `AND` and `OR`).

For example, a `BlockObject` could look like this:

`Object1` `AND` `Object2` `OR` `Object3` `AND` `Object4`

What is the most suitable schema to represent this information in a relational database?

In my case, the only possible operation is adding a new object at the end of the list, but a solution which generalize to more complex operations (swaping objects) would be much appreciated.

Comment: "store an operation between 2 sequent objects from the block" & "more complex operations (swaping objects)" are not clear, and it's not clear what your example is an example of. Please use enough text to explain yourself. Please give *some* relational design even if you think is has disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you basically need to store a tree-like composite structure in the database.  Try to avoid that, but if you really need to -- quick google: http://www.theresearchkitchen.com/archives/57 or [Help regarding composite pattern with hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603742/help-regarding-composite-pattern-with-hibernate)

For perfomance reasons, I would recommend to map only relationship to parent (with lazy fetch), not to children and create special dao methods to load the whole tree, subtree etc.

Persisting this type of structure to Neo4J would be better and much faster, if available.